# gridview dataformatstring custom currency

Tags: asp.net, xml, currency, dataformat

IS there any way, using the dataformatstring, to move the Euro (€) currency symbol to the beggining of the value without hardcoding the euro symbol in the xml?

Example : Using `{0:C}` I get 1234€ and what i want is to get €1234 . I can't find a solution for this without having to hardcode de euro symbol like `€{0:g}` .

Any clue ?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `CurrencyPositivePattern` to `0`:

```
NumberFormatInfo nfi = (NumberFormatInfo)NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.Clone();
nfi.CurrencyPositivePattern = 0;
```

You will likely want to set the [`CurrencyNegativePattern`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencynegativepattern.aspx) as well. The link provides all of the patterns.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem safest to specify the default currency symbol.

As whatever your defualt culture is (e.g in case of French Currrency there is a dual currency either it can be the local currency or euros)

NumberFormatInfo numberFormatInfo= (NumberFormatInfo)NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.Clone();
numberFormatInfo.CurrencySymbol = "€";

Comment: This wouldn't do anything. It's already that symbol, the OP wants to change the format.